# Function to fill automatically

Tags: vbscript

I'm new with VBScript, and I need to find a way to fill with zero a group of an IP address when it does not have three characters per group. For example, I got an IP address, "10.67.131.1", and I need to save it in a variable as "010.067.131.001".

I already have a function which gets the IP address, but I'll never know how many characters it'll have in which group. So I need a function that fills it automatically.

Comment: Hi Ken, I have do this because there is an old program in the company that I work, which gets the IPaddress from an INI file and checks if the IP has 15 characters, if not, if does not accept. We tried to contact the manufacturer, but they do not give support to the program anymore. So that's the why I need do this.

Answer (score 3):

@KenWhite asks a good question in the comments, but assuming that you have a good reason for wanting to store IP addresses in a left-padded manner then you can certainly use VBScript to convert to that form. Here is a simple function which does so:

```
Option Explicit

Function PadGroups(s)
    Dim A,i, group
    A = Split(s,".")

    For i = 0 To UBound(A)
        group = A(i)
        If Len(group) < 3 Then 
            group = String(3-Len(group),"0") & group
            A(i) = group
        End If  
    Next

    PadGroups = Join(A,".")
End Function

'test
MsgBox PadGroups("10.67.131.1" )
```